# Plotting a sequence of points defined by a simple formula

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

This shouldn't be difficult, but I cannot make it work. I expected this code to generate the plot a certain sequence of blue points on a black circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\def\n{7}
\def\anglerot{222.5}
\draw(0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \i \in {0,...,\n} 
    \fill[color=blue] (cos (\i*\anglerot), sin (\i*\anglerot)) circle (.02);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in` instead of `\in`.

Version 1: `\pgfmathsetmacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\anglerot{222.5}
\draw(0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}  {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{cos (\i*\anglerot)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sin (\i*\anglerot)}
    \fill[color=blue] (\x, \y) circle (.02);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Version 2: braces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\def\n{7}
\def\anglerot{222.5}
\draw(0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \i in {0,...,\n} {
    \fill[color=blue] ({cos (\i*\anglerot)}, {sin (\i*\anglerot)}) circle (.02);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```